# rational exponents inconsistency

Tags: real-numbers

Why is there an inconsistency for (-1)^0.6 (or (-1)^(6/10)). I know in school I was taught to simplify the exponent to 3/5, which results in -1. However, when I leave the exponent as 6/10, I get a either the 10th root of (-1)^6 = 1 or ((-1)^(1/10))^6. Is there a way this can be explained without just simply saying to simplify the rational exponent first?

Comment: At the simplest, $(x^a)^b$ does __not__ generally equal $x^{ab}$ when $x$ is not positive. (The simplest example of why it won't work is to compare $(-1)^{2*(1/2)}$ with $((-1)^2)^{1/2}$).  There are a bunch of more detailed answers explaining this already on the site. Hopefully someone will drop a link to them here, or you can search for them.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I'll have a look.